# JBOSS - The transaction is not active error

Tags: jboss, transactions, heap-size

I get transaction timeout error as follow, when I run my JBOSS.

```
SystemException The following problem occured: null; nested exception is:
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.inactive] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.a
rjunacore.inactive] The transaction is not active!; - nested throwable: (java.lang.IllegalStateException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transactio
n.arjunacore.inactive] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.inactive] The transaction is not active!): null; nested exception is:

        java.lang.IllegalStateException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.inactive] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.a
rjunacore.inactive] The transaction is not active!; - nested throwable: (java.lang.IllegalStateException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transactio
n.arjunacore.inactive] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.inactive] The transaction is not active!): [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jt
a.transaction.arjunacore.inactive] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.inactive] The transaction is not active! called at com.jco
ffee.base.global.ExceptionMapper.handleException(ExceptionMapper.java:240)
```

I googled the error and came across a solution which involves changing the transaction timeout from 300 to a higher value and I did so,

```
   <mbean code="com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService"
      name="jboss:service=TransactionManager">
      <attribute name="TransactionTimeout">3000</attribute>
      <attribute name="ObjectStoreDir">${jboss.server.data.dir}/tx-object-store</attribute> 
   </mbean>
```

but still the error persist.

My heapsizes are as follow:

```
-Xms2000m  
-Xmx2000m
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Before the error occurs, Garbage collector unloads a large number of classes and the RAM is left only with few MB of free space. I have aroung 6GB of RAM + 3GB of pagefiles

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: it is a BeanManagedTransaction?

Comment: @GabrielAramburu Yeah it is.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen that exception when the transaction timeout is reached, I think that increasing the timeout should solve the problem.
Try to set the transaction timeout to [UserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html) object like is showed [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout). (Using BMT section)

Comment: In my case this was the issue, but I changed the default timeout for all my transactions on `<coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>` in the transactions subsystem of Wildfly (I was not specifying any value and the default is 300. My transactions needed a little bit longer than that though).